# why length of empty list is not 0 in re.split

Tags: python, list, python-re

```
import re
a=''
b=re.split(" |,",a)
print(b)
print(len(b))
print(type(b))
```

why len(b) is 1 instead of 0, but indeed b is empty list,and I cannot find any explanations in python re doc

Comment: `b` is not an empty list, it's a list with an empty sting in it.

Comment: If len(b) is 1 then b is not an empty list. You are misinterpreting the (unspecified) output you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` is not the empty list. It is a list with an empty string.

The rule is that `split` returns 1 more element than there are (non-overlapping) occurrences of the separator in the string. So when there is one occurrence of the separator, you'll get a list of two strings. If there are zero occurrences, you'll get a list with one string.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an empty list or is it a list with an empty string?  Split() will always return an array of at least 1 because if it can't split the string up, it will return the string as a whole.  In this case, the empty string, but it still counts as an item in the list.